# Upload entire HTML project directory to EE2 possible?

Tags: ee2

Required to use ExpressionEngine 2.7.3 due to Hudson module (No API either).
We built our site locally in HTML/CSS/JS since that's what we're used to and before we start copying it over we wanted to check if there's a easier way or if it's possible to just upload our current directory to EE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use all your existing site HTML/CSS/JS to setup templates. Though it's not as simple as just "uploading our current directory to EE." Do you have more specific questions? This is a bit vague to provide a concise answer.